# visual-studio-code Powershell command auto-complete in the editor panel not working

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, command, intellisense

I've just started using Visual Studio Code for working with Powershell.  I've loaded the powershell extension, and when I connect to Exchange auto-completion of cmdlets works in the integrated powershell window, but it doesn't work in the to peditor panel.  How can I get cmdlet auto-complete or intellisense to work in the editor panel? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say if you configured you VSCode environment to make PowerShell the default language. If you look in the right hand corner of the editor, it will tell you what language is currently set to. Show your user settings. In your user settings, you should have lines like this in place (just an example from mine, tweak as needed for your use case - see the docs for details on the VSCode user settings.)…

```
"extensions.autoUpdate": true,
"files.defaultLanguage": "powershell",
"powershell.scriptAnalysis.enable": true,
"powershell.startAutomatically": true,
"powershell.integratedConsole.focusConsoleOnExecute": false,
"powershell.enableProfileLoading": true,
"powershell.developer.editorServicesLogLevel": "Verbose",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
"editor.tabCompletion": "on",
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
"terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "default",
"window.title": "${activeEditorLong}",
"powershell.powerShellExePath": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
"powershell.scriptAnalysis.settingsPath": "ScriptAnalyzerSettings.psd1",
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"editor.cursorStyle": "line-thin",
"shellLauncher.shells.windows": [
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
        "label": "PowerShell 5.1"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\6\\pwsh.exe",
        "label": "PowerShell 6.0"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
        "label": "cmd"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "label": "Git bash"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe",
        "label": "WSL Bash"
    },
```

VSCode is notorious for intellisense stopping for no apparent reason (it's my #1 grip with it), but in most cases, all you have to do is backspace to the beginning of your command and try again, or use the CRTL+Spacebar to have intellisense kick it, or type reload.

Again, this happens to me all the time, and the above brings things back. It's annoying, but it is what it is.

Comment: If you are using a prefix, as I do all the time, you must use that prefix in the cmdlet. For example, when I do this my prefix are EXO and EXP, for obvious reasons. Then cmdlets are called using Get-EXOMailbox or Get-EXPMailbox, not the default cmdlet name. This is documented on TechNet, and on the MS Docs site.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been using ISE forever, and trying to get with the times.  It seems like it's working, but in a limited way.  I connect and import Exchange cmdlets from on-premises and Exchange online in my profile.  Intellisense seems to  only be able to tab complete one or the other set of cmdlets.  I import the on-prem cmdlets as normal, and add a prefix to the Exchange Online cmdlets.  So, for example, it will either tab complete "get-mailbox" or "get-EXOmailbox", but it can't do both.

Comment: I would paste in a code snippet, but none of the documented ways are working for me, and the comment only allows like 5 chars it seems.  I have to RTFM just to post here apparently :)

Comment: I use a  prefix for EXO, but not for on-prem.  So, I type in get-mailbox to retreive an on-prem mailbox, and get-EXOmailbox to retrieve an EXO mailbox.  Are you saying I need to use a prefix for the on-prem cmdlets as well?

Comment: The moment you use a prefix, then yep, you need to use the prefix. If you are not using a prefix, use the default.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I've tried, but it's not able to handle the same imported cmdlets with different prefixes.  I imported on-premise cmdlets using prefix ONP, and Exchange online with EXO.  It tab completes for the ONP, but not the EXO cmdlets. It just sits there "loading", and backspacing cntrl+space doesn't help. It seems it only completes the first set of cmdlets imported, and can't do the subsequent.

Comment: I've seen this in VSCode, which is why it is not my default, yet. I still default  to the ISE 95.5% of the time, VSCode only when needed, PowerShell Studio for the rest. VSCode intelligence just stops working / or won't work for whatever reason, and backspace and start over, crtl+spacebar, restart, reload, or shut down and restart is the only way to get it back. This has nothing to do with what you are importing. In all my experience to date is 100% VSCode issue. I've messed with it with and without additional extension, same issue.

Comment: I am not sure if VSCode needs a default language as you write in the first line. I use it with several languages, there is no default. I thought that `"files.associations": {"*.ps1": "powershell" },` is all to add to settings.json to have the PS Features from the official PS extension.

Comment: Timo,  VSCode does require and has a default language on the install before you ever install the PS extension and that language is 'Plain Text', since it's first and foremost a text code editor. Once you install the extension does not change that. You can set that to Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core. Doing the setting you chose will just fire off whatever version you have set at the OS level. You config VSC to be what you want it to be at startup or your use case, and what I am showing is as defined in the VSCode docs, not something I made up. It is an option in the settings screen.

Comment: Just open up the Settings screen, and filter for 'default language' and read why you'd use it. Of course 'file association' has its explanation on the same screen. 'This is also not the first time this default language setting conversation has been brought up on SO or on the web. Just search for it ... ['vscode set a default language'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27vscode+set+a+default+language%27&t=h_&ia=web). Again, this is about choice/options to config VScode or any dev/editor tool. Do what works for you, regardless of any other opinion.